# How to execute a function in Python based on time provided by argument

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, gil

How to execute a function in Python based on time provided by seconds argument.

```
def timerfn(seconds, fn, *args):
    #start some timer
    #if function first launch is > "seconds", abort
    #if function doing great.. repeat it and stop at "seconds"
```

As i'm thinking over it time.clock() can't really help here, because a function can be really tough and it will not ever reach a counter-timer to show some result or abort.

Do i have to use threading module? i don't know much about threads, but from what i read - you can have only a one thread in work according to GIL, and this process really needs 2 threads at same time.. or some other trick that i don't know.

Comment: What is the `powerup` function for?

Comment: it's just for representation, input can be any function, should i remove it?

Comment: A couple of very interesting answers to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call

Answer (score 0):

The GIL means, always just one Thread is running, but it doesn't mean that you're restricted to one Thread.

Sounds like you want [threading.Timer](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Timer).

Comment: how can threading.Timer help here? can it dynamically break out of infinite loop or something like that?

Comment: Yes if you use it correctly you can use it to set an event (also in the threading module) which breaks out of the loop